# segue and passing data from uialertcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller, unwind-segue

I've been trying to passing some data to model file to be used in another view controller by using pop-up alert after user tab the save button it suppose to trigger prepare function and unwind to tableview on another view controller.

```
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    saveFilesName()
}
```

Then,

```
    func saveFilesName() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save As", message: "Please enter the file name", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(nameField) -> Void in
        nameField.placeholder = "Enter the file name"
        nameField.textAlignment = .center
    })
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(descField) -> Void in
        descField.placeholder = "Enter the your description"
        descField.textAlignment = .center
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (actions: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (actions: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let nameFieldData = alert.textFields![0]
        let descFieldData = alert.textFields![1]
        self.fileName = nameFieldData.text ?? ""
        self.descData = descFieldData.text ?? ""
        print(alert.textFields![0])
        let saveCSV = self.saveCSVFiles()
        print(saveCSV.lastPathComponent)


        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToCSVList", sender: self)
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but after I tab the save button it unwind to the table view as intended but the prepare method always return  **The save button was not pressed, cancelling** which mean the prepare method didn't being triggered properly

```
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCSVList" {
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

    let nsurl = String(describing: csvFile)
    let name = fileName ?? ""
    let description = descData ?? ""
    let photo = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "defaultImage")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: nsurl)

    print("yeah")
    csv = CSVData(name: name, description: description, photo: photo, url: url)
    }
}
```

any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Why did you check the segue identifier since you only performSegue when the user presses "Save" action ? Withdraw your guard statement if there is only one unwindSegue. Your saveButton you have it as an outlet ? Or just an action function ? I think also there is a misunderstood on how to correctly implement unwindSegue, check this article : https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f

Comment: @Arrabidas92 I didn't noticed the first draft, which i started the button as outlet. well, to answer your question the saveButton is a action function which call an alertview then user need to tab save button in order to pass some data to another view controller along with perform segue

Comment: @Arrabidas92 that's just work ! thank

Comment: great ! Can you up vote my comment at least ?